# Redirecting all Unregistered Subdomains to Catch-All

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

We'd like to redirect all misspelled subdomains to a catch-all (primary domain), ex. dalls.domain.com needs to resolve to domain.com. Due to the very large number of subdomains we have, we can't simply create redirects for each possible spelling. Is there a way to wildcard redirect all non-registered subdomains to domain.com?

Thanks for any help or insight!

Comment: This has an answer over at serverfault:

[http://serverfault.com/questions/82306/apache-default-catch-all-virtual-host][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/82306/apache-default-catch-all-virtual-host

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but you can redirect all 404's quite easily with htaccess. The only downside is that all mispelled(or non-existent) directories and files will also redirect.
You can do this by adding this to your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com
```

Hope this helps! I will edit this answer if I find a specific redirect for just wrong sub-domains.